# Problem with booting ubuntu , No botable device found?

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04

When i open my computer to run ubuntu it says:
[image: [Click here to see the image]

But i can begin the OS only using this method:

open my computer and when i see the "dell" logo i still clicking on "F12" to show the boot options then select "Internal HDD"  like the image below : 
[image: Click here to see the image]
Then the ubuntu is working , but i want to start it automatically when i open my device!

How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your boot order; if you say Ubuntu loads when you select Internal HDD, change the boot order and put HDD on top. Don't forget to save that boot config.

Comment: Yes you are right, but i have tried to do that  , but i have failed 

Comment: I tried again then i have done successfully, thank you so much ❤️